# Android: 1 dip on LDPI

Tags: android, pixel, android-screen-support, density-independent-pixel

I'm using a view which's height is 1dip. Now I'm wondering what it will do on a LDPI screen. Unfortunately, I haven't got a LDPI screen to test on, so that's why I'm asking you guys. 1 dip on LDPI means 0.75 px. What will android do, will it show 1px or 0px?

Comment: You can create an emulator for ldpi resolution and test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be 1px for sure, you could see the same in Graphical Layout tab of eclipse, and changing screen size to smallest. Also if you really want to test you may want to create an emulator with ldpi screen and test the same.

Comment: Thanks, although I do not really confide in the Graphical Layout tab (it's been showing wrong things in the past) I'll just assume it'll be 1px